# How to get my Green Party email address added to the CiviMail from dropdown list

Tags: civimail

I am the Membership Secretary for the Croydon and Sutton Local Party. In the past I have been able to send out mailings to our members. However, since the update on civi my Green party email address cannot be manually entered so that I am unable to send out mailings.

How can I rectify this please so that my email can be added to the from section of a  mailing?

Answer (score 3):

This is a setting in CiviCRM setting under Administer --> System settings --> Outbound E-mail.

There is a checkbox to allow different from e-mail addresses. If this is checkbox is set to no you can only send from a predefined list of senders.

The from e-mail addresses could be found under Administer --> CiviMail --> From Email Addresses